# Deny access to js and css

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I want to deny access to the js, css files
If someone trying to access such file.js or file.css
the website redirect him to 404

but below code is not working. because it even block serving web pages.
i just need to block access from js css files being browsed by users

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(js|css)$ - [F]
```

Comment: It is the client browser that requests the JS and CSS files that a page says to include.  As you noticed, blocking access breaks the page.  To see this in Google Chrome, press the F12 key to open developer tools then go to a web page.  So: you can't do this.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It is an effort to implement a protection and that protection will never work reliable (it is trivial to get around it). So what for? You publish those files with your site anyway for everyone to see and read.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the following script on my website for the same purpose. Could you modify your .htaccess file like this:?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.js$ /path/to/404-error-page [R,L]
RewriteRule \.css$ /path/to/404-error-page [R,L]
```

`.+\.(js|css)$` that regex means match any files with the .js and .css extensions so it can also block valid requests for .js and .css files needed by your web pages.

Comment: Good answer.  Note that this blocks "leeching" where some other site uses the files, but it does not prevent the user from copying/saving/looking at the content of the files if that's what @TomKine is hoping for.

Comment: yes @DaveS i dont want looking at the content of the files.  but i think obfuscate is good ideal

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from enter_ip_from_allowed_client
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</FilesMatch>
```